# Two bootmanagers at boot?

Tags: windows-10, boot-manager

How it this be?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/LTOujYB.jpg]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/HX65UDE.jpg]

If I choose first bootmanager I have this `bcdedit` configuration (current)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/EuE9dEV.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dShBoMn.png]

If I choose second I have different `bcdedit` configuration (default)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/aY8dTgp.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/HBJjQiU.png]

But Windows RE environment working only at first (current) boot manager.

How remove unneeded boot manager and get allinone ONE working boot manager option?

Comment: What do you see in your BIOS boot menu ?